# How do I debug portlet rendering?

Tags: plone

Changes I make to the ViewPageTemplateFile() are not taking effect.

The render() method is not getting called as the page is being displayed although update() is.

Is the result of the render method cached/memoized in some way?

Comment: When / how the issue happens? Does Plone restart help? Could we get some example code? The result might be cached if your site has plone.app.caching add-on installed, but this is unlikely.

Comment: no custom code. I am using plone.portlet.collection. I can see the <dl class="portlet portletCollection"> show up in the output. No changes to collection.pt seem to take effect. Created a render() method for the Renderer class but never gets called. update() gets called.

Comment: How do you change collection.pt and where do you place the file? Does restart help? Is Plone running in debug mode?

Comment: Tried to add my own css class and also tried to call plone_log in collection.pt. Changed it in place, i.e. buildout-cache/eggs/plone.portlet.collection-xxxx/plone/portlet/collection/collection.pt. Did not have any effect. Plone is in debug mode running in console (fg) mode.

Comment: http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/portlets/tips.html#update-and-render

Comment: I am trying to use the code from the section "Rendering a portlet" from the document above. I am putting this code in an External method for easy debugging. What can i use for the "view" variable in order to set the portlet renderer?

Comment: ok.. i used the view=portal.restrictedTraverse('@@plone') and am able to step into the render method. Why doesn't this happen from Plone? Have turned off caching from Plone control panel.